# Действия при выборе пункта выпадающего списка в django

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте! Очень долго не могу решить следующую проблему: мне необходимо реализовать расписание уроков на сайте django. то есть выглядеть это должно следующим образом - на странице есть выпадающий список с классами (5"А", 5"Б"....11"В") и кнопка "Показать". При выборе элемента выпадающего списка должна открываться расписание уроков на неделю для выбранного класса. В идеале - реализация без редиректа, но думаю, такое я точно не осилю, так как на данный момент не могу сделать подобного и со сменой страницы. Итак, у меня имеется следующее:
**В models.py**:

```
class Classes(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'classes'
        verbose_name_plural = "Классы"
        verbose_name = "Класс"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name = 'Классы')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Lessons(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "lessons"
        verbose_name_plural = "Уроки"
        verbose_name = "Уроки"
    lessons_class = models.ForeignKey(Classes)
    lessons_creationdate = models.DateField()
    lessons_weekcontent = RichTextField()
```

Соответственно, в админке я вручную ввожу классы(5"А"...) и тд, после чего вручную ввожу расписание уроков на неделю и выбираю к какому классу оно относится. **Далее, в forms.py:**

```
class LessonsForm(forms.ModelForm):
        classname = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Classes.objects.all(),empty_label="Выберите класс",widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'dropdown'}),label="Класс")
        class Meta:
            model = Lessons
            fields = ('lessons_class',)
```

Огромное количество раз перечитал документацию django, но все равно смутно себе представляю, как должен выглядеть при этом **views.py. У меня имеется следующее:**

```
def LessonsShow(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = LessonsForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/about/')

    else:
        form = LessonsForm()

    return render(request, 'timetable.html', {'form': form})
```

Я так понимаю, у меня должна быть какая-то обработка после if form.is_valid():, но не представляю, что там должно быть. **И наконец в шаблоне timetable.html**:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<form  method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.classname }}
  <input type="submit" value="Показать расписание">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

В итоге на странице http://127.0.0.1:8000/timetable/ у меня есть выпадающий список, с классами из моей базы данных, но при выборе какого-то из них и нажатия кнопки, ничего не происходит. Что сделать, чтобы при выборе значения этого выпадающего списка и нажатия на кнопку "Показать расписание" открывалась соотвествующая этому классу таблица с расписанием уроков на неделю? Очень надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

Comment: Зачем вам форма? Сделайте View для расписания по классам, а на странице выбора классов выведите их список со ссылками.

Comment: Если вам именно форму хочется, то в форме вместо action="POST", поставьте action="GET". А во View просмотра расписания на неделю забирайте GET и по его параметрам фильтруйте queryset. Сейчас не совсем понятно, какой конкретно результат нужен: страница с ajax подгрузкой, отдельные страницы расписаний на неделю по классам, одно обльшое расписание с возможностью фильтровать его по парамтерам?

Comment: Нужны отдельные страницы расписаний. Спасибо за советы)

Answer (score 2):

В комментариях решение фактически найдено. Если делаем без js то самый простой способ через форму с отправкой по GET.

После нажатия кнопки открывается новое окно, с переданными в url параметрами. Не seo url, но оно и не нужно тут.

```
/timetable/?name=7Б
```

в views разбираем данные из GET

```
klass = request.GET['name']
Classes.objects.get(name=klass)
```

Далее в шаблон выводим как нужно.

Одна страница, нет редиректов, можно давать ссылку, переходить из закладок.

Если очень хочется "красивые" url, то нужно сразу переходить со списка на нужную страницу, для этого используется javascript код открывающий ее.

Либо тот же редирект, но тогда нужно будет писать еще одну функцию обработки или в текущей проверять на присутствие параметров.

Главное чтобы была возможность по ссылке перейти на нужный класс, пусть и из закладок. Никто не учится сразу во всей школе, а выбирать каждый раз из списка может раздражать.